# Передать в type file объекты

Tags: jquery

Имеется такой код:

```
<form action="/admin/addBanner" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" type="file" name="file" multiple>
<button class="d-td-button-action fs-medium ff-SansNarrow" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
....
//в скрипте имеется массив файлов(изображений) хранящихся в files
var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
```

Как передать объекты из files в input type file

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function() {
 // В dataTransfer помещаются изображения которые перетащили в область div
 jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
 // Максимальное количество загружаемых изображений за одни раз
 var maxFiles = 1;

 // Оповещение по умолчанию
 var errMessage = 0;
 
 // Кнопка выбора файлов
 var defaultUploadBtn = $('.upload-btn');
 
 // Массив для всех изображений
 var dataArray = [];
 // Метод при падении файла в зону загрузки
 $('.upload-container').on('drop', function(e) { 
  // Передаем в files все полученные изображения
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
  if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
   // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
   loadInView(files);
  } else {
   alert('Вы не можете загружать изображения больше '+maxFiles+'!'); 
   files.length = 0; return;
  }
 });
 
 // При нажатии на кнопку выбора файлов
 defaultUploadBtn.on('change', function() {
     // Заполняем массив выбранными изображениями
     var files = $(this)[0].files;
     // Проверяем на максимальное количество файлов
  if (files.length <= maxFiles) {
   // Передаем массив с файлами в функцию загрузки на предпросмотр
   loadInView(files);
   // Очищаем инпут файл путем сброса формы
            $('.upload-form').each(function(){
              this.reset();
   });
  } else {
   alert('Вы не можете загружать изображения больше '+maxFiles+'!'); 
   files.length = 0;
  }
 });
 
 // Функция загрузки изображений на предросмотр
 function loadInView(files) {
  // Показываем обасть предпросмотра
  $('.uploaded-holder').show();
  
  // Для каждого файла
  $.each(files, function(index, file) {
      
   // Несколько оповещений при попытке загрузить не изображение
   if (!files[index].type.match('image.*')) {
    
    if(errMessage == 0) {
     $('.upload-container span').html('Ошибка!');
     ++errMessage
    }
    return false;
   }
   else {
    $('.upload-container span').html("или перетащите");
   }
   
   // Проверяем количество загружаемых элементов
   if((dataArray.length+files.length) > maxFiles) {
    alert('Вы не можете загружать изображения больше '+maxFiles+'!'); return; 
   }
   
   // Создаем новый экземпляра FileReader
   var fileReader = new FileReader();
    // Инициируем функцию FileReader
    fileReader.onload = (function(file) {
     
     return function(e) {
      // Помещаем URI изображения в массив
      dataArray.push({name : file.name, value : this.result});
      addImage((dataArray.length-1));
     }; 
      
    })(files[index]);
   // Производим чтение картинки по URI
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
  return false;
 }
  
 // Процедура добавления эскизов на страницу
 function addImage(ind) {
  // Если индекс отрицательный значит выводим весь массив изображений
  if (ind < 0 ) { 
  start = 0; end = dataArray.length; 
  } else {
  // иначе только определенное изображение 
  start = ind; end = ind+1; } 
  // Оповещения о загруженных файлах
  if(dataArray.length == 0) {
   $('.uploaded-holder').hide();
  }
  // Цикл для каждого элемента массива
  for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
   // размещаем загруженные изображения
   if($('.dropped-container > .image').length <= maxFiles) { 
    $('.dropped-container').append('<img class="d-table-img" src="'+dataArray[i].value+'">'); 
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 
 // next script
 
 var dropZone = $('.upload-container');

 $('.upload-btn').focus(function() {
  $('label').addClass('focus');
 })
 .focusout(function() {
  $('label').removeClass('focus');
 });


 dropZone.on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', function(){
  return false;
 });

 dropZone.on('dragover dragenter', function() {
  dropZone.addClass('dragover');
 });

 dropZone.on('dragleave', function(e) {
  let dx = e.pageX - dropZone.offset().left;
  let dy = e.pageY - dropZone.offset().top;
  if ((dx < 0) || (dx > dropZone.width()) || (dy < 0) || (dy > dropZone.height())) {
   dropZone.removeClass('dragover');
  }
 });

 dropZone.on('drop', function(e) {
  dropZone.removeClass('dragover');
  let files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    sendFiles(files);
 });

 $('.upload-btn').change(function() {
  let files = this.files;
    sendFiles(files);
 });
  
  
  function sendFiles(files) {
  var json;
  let Data = new FormData();
  Data.append('text', 'fdgd');
  $(files).each(function(index, file) {
   Data.append('file', file);
  });

  $.ajax({
   url: '/admin/addBanner',
   type: 'post',
   data: Data,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function(result) {
    json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
     if (json.url) {
      window.location.href = '/' + json.url;
     } else {
      alert(json.status + ' - ' + json.message);
     }
   }
  });
 }
  $('form').submit(function(event) { })
  
});
```

```css
.d-table {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column nowrap;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 padding: 45px;
}

.d-th {
 display: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.d-tr {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.d-td {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-basis: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 min-width: 100px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 
 white-space: normal;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.d-td-img {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 flex-grow: 3;
 flex-basis: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 min-width: 100px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 
 white-space: normal;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.d-table-img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
}






.upload-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 110px;
 height: 110px;
 outline: 2px dashed #5d5d5d;
 outline-offset: -12px;
 background-color: rgba(76,175,80,.6);
 text-align: center;
}

.upload-container-img {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 user-select: none;
}

.upload-container-label {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-container-label:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.upload-container input[type=file] {
 display:none;
}

.upload-container-label input[type=file]:focus + label {
 outline: 1px solid #0078d7;
 outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}

.upload-container.dragover {
 background-color: rgba(76,175,80,.2);
 outline-offset: -17px;
}











.drop-files {
 position:relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 140px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 4px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 padding-top:80px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.drop-files p {
 clear:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.uploaded-holder {
 display: none;
 position:relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropped-files {
 display:block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 950px;
}


.drop-button {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 font-size: 1em;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #FFF;
}

.dropped-files .image {
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background: #fff;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 0 7px 7px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}


.dropped-files .delete {
 padding: 7px 6px 4px 6px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 box-shadow: none;
 font-size: 1em;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

.dropped-files .delete:hover {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
ы
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="d-table ff-SansNarrow">
<form action="/admin/addBanner" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="d-tr">
     <span class="d-td-img">
      <div class="dropped-container">
       <!--<a href="#img1">
        <img class="d-table-img" src="/public/images/banners/74.jpg">
       </a>-->
      </div>
     </span>
     <span class="d-td" style="flex-grow: 2;">
     <div>
      <div class="upload-container">
       <input class="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" type="file" name="file" multiple>
       <label class="upload-container-label" for="upload-btn" data-count="1">Выберите файл</label>
       <span>или перетащите</span>
      </div>
     </div>
     </span>
     <span class="d-td">
      <input class="d-th" type="text" name="file2">
      <button class="d-td-button-action" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
     </span>
    </div>
  </div>  
 </form>
</div>
```

Если в скрипт добавить $('form').submit(function(event) {
    } то будет открываться файл, а надо что бы выполнялся скрипт. И еще в функции sendFiles(files) я добавляю Data.append('text', 'fdgd'); так как без него не передается, почему не знаю

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98122/discussion-on-question-by-helldrg---type-file-).

Answer (score 1):

Передать в type file объекты программно я так понял нельзя, как я понял, так изначально задумано разработчиками.

Решил так же два вопроса:

1. Если в скрипт добавить `$('form').submit(function(event) { }` то будет открываться файл, а надо что бы выполнялся скрипт.
   Ответ: необходимо было поставить в конце закрывающуюся скобку;
2. В функции `sendFiles(files)` я добавлял `Data.append('text', 'fdgd');` так как без него не приходили данные в обработчик.
   Ответ: на сервере стояла проверка `if (!empty($_POST))`, так как я отправлял только файлы переменная `$_POST` была пустой. Проверку заменил на `if (!empty($_FILES))` и все заработало.

Спасибо большое господину [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за помощь и терпение =)

Comment: добавь описание как в итоге решил

Comment: я не знаю как это описать. Я разобрался что пропустил скобку здесь  $('form').submit(function(event) { }) и что файл при передачи по пост запросу хранится в $_FILES а не в в $_POST

Comment: мне нужно было записывать в type file объекты, потому что дроп не работал файлов. Когда я добавил $('form').submit(function(event) он у меня заработал, но при добавлении файла по кнопке файл два раза сохранялся на сервере

Comment: вот именно то что ты сейчас написал в комментариях и должно было быть в ответе :)

Comment: Вскоре я понял что проблема в submit он отправляет пост запрос и скрипт еще. Я функцию заменил $('.btn-form').click(function(event) {

Comment: через кнопку все хорошо стало работать, но при дропе файл не выбирался и появился баг. Раньше ответ с сервера приходил в alert, а сейчас стал приходить в виде исходного кода

Comment: вот тут я расписал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1019350/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-ajax-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: в итоге у меня не полностью рабочий код и приводить его в ответе из за этого не хочется =(

Comment: это уже другой вопрос. Тут у тебя было два конкретных вопроса: 1. Если в скрипт добавить $('form').submit(function(event) { } то будет открываться файл, а надо что бы выполнялся скрипт. 2. И еще в функции sendFiles(files) я добавляю Data.append('text', 'fdgd'); так как без него не передается,

ты разобрался с обоими - вот и напиши как и что

Comment: Сделал, расписал как мог =)